# how to delete item from a list of key-value pairs in python

Tags: python, list, key-value

I have a `list` of `key-value` pair in `python`. A sample of this list is:

```
list_pairs = [{'text': 'Zen', 'value': 'Zen'}, {'text': 'Global', 'value': 'Global'}, {'text': 'Corporation', 'value': 'Corporation'}]
```

Now I have a string `str1` and what I want to do is to match it with `text` field of each `key-value` pair and delete the one which matches. So if my string is `Zen` then delete `{'text': 'Zen', 'value': 'Zen'}` from the list.

I tried to do `del list_pairs[str1]` but it throws error as `list indices can only be integers and not str`.

How can I delete the items from my list of key-value pair?

Comment: You have a `list` with `dict` objects. You need to use integer indices to access the `list` items, or iterate over it directly `for d in list_pairs: ...` then you can index into the `dict` objects with strings, i.e. `d['text'] == 'Zen'`.

Comment: You have a list of dicts NOT "key-value" pairs, there's a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Delete

```
l = [{'text': 'Zen', 'value': 'Zen'}, {'text': 'Global', 'value': 'Global'}, {'text': 'Corporation', 'value': 'Corporation'}]

collect = []
for n, d in enumerate(l):
    for k in d:
        if d[k] == 'Zen':
            print(k)
            collect.append([n, k])

for v in collect:
    del l[v[0]][v[1]]

print(l)
```

### out:

```
text
value
[{}, {'text': 'Global', 'value': 'Global'}, {'text': 'Corporation', 'value': 'Corporation'}]
```

## List comprehension

```
l = [{'text': 'Zen', 'value': 'Zen'}, {'text': 'Global', 'value': 'Global'}, {'text': 'Corporation', 'value': 'Corporation'}]

collect = []
[[collect.append([n, k]) for k in d if d[k] == "Zen"] for n, d in enumerate(l)]

for v in collect:
    del l[v[0]][v[1]]

print(l)
```

### out:

```
[{}, {'text': 'Global', 'value': 'Global'}, {'text': 'Corporation', 'value': 'Corporation'}]
```

Answer (score 4):

True @smac89. 
Concise answer would be :

```
new_list_pair = [d for d in list_pairs if d['text'] != str1]
```

Thanks @ juanpa.arrivillaga

Not recommend incorrect version:

```
str1 = 'Zen'
for d in list_pairs:
    if d['text'] == str1:
        list_pairs.remove(d)
```

Comment: You can easily turn this into list comprehension

Comment: You are unsafely removing from a list while iterating over it

Comment: Your concise version is what I would recommend. Don't mess with a list as you iterate through it, just create a new one.

Comment: Note, the two versions are *not equivalent*, and your second version is still incorrect.

Comment: Also, using `list.remove` here is very inefficient, since it will iterate from the beginning of the list checking equality for each element until it finds one, but you already know the element you want to remove..

Answer (score 0):

```
def del_match(str):
     for index,item in enumerate(list_pairs):
         if item['text'] is str:
             del list_pairs[index]
```

I am leaving this bad answer here, please refer to the comments below on why it is a bad answer, may be it will help people to get more out of this problem.

Comment: You are unsafely removing from a list while iterating over it

Comment: Thanks, what are the implications of doing so ?

Comment: You will skip items. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: So, try this on the following data: `[{'text': 'Zen', 'value': 'Zen'}, {'text': 'Zen', 'value': 'Zen'}, {'text': 'Global', 'value': 'Global'}, {'text': 'Corporation', 'value': 'Corporation'}]`

Comment: You can simply iterate over a copy for a quick fix, i.e. do `for i, item in enumerate(list_pairs[:])`